# Is it supposed that developers should implement their own XXXProperties in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am reading about javafx properties and can't understand why non abstract classes we can use for creating instances of properties (for example `SimpleStringProperty`) have `Simple` word in their names. As I know `Simple` in implementation means `basic` implementation of something.

Is it supposed that developers should implement their own XXXProperty that must extend `XXXPropertyBase` in JavaFX?

Let's consider for example SimpleStringProperty.

```
 java.lang.Object
    javafx.beans.binding.StringExpression
        javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringProperty
            javafx.beans.property.StringProperty
                javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase
                    javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
```

Should we develop our own `OurStringProperty` that will extend `StringPropertyBase`?

At the same time in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html) it is said that `javafx.beans.property.StringProperty class provides a full implementation of a Property wrapping a String value`. So why do we need this `SimpleStringProperty`? How to explain it?

Comment: I'd say that Javadoc is misleading; if you look at the source of `StringProperty` it is certainly _not_ a "full implementation". Unless I'm interpreting that phrase differently from what's intended. Anyway, it's `StringPropertyBase` that manages listeners, unidirectional binding, and the value. The `SimpleStringProperty` class handles the `bean` and `name`. I'm guessing this was done to allow developers to subclass with varying degrees of "already implemented".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample how to add a simple Object-based property to your class using the implementations provided by JavaFX (similar classes exist for String and primitive types):

```
private final ObjectProperty<Foo> foo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this,
        "foo", null);

public final Foo getFoo() {
    return fooProperty().get();
}

public final void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    fooProperty().set(foo);
}

public ObjectProperty<Foo> fooProperty() {
    return foo;
}
```

Here is a sample of a read-only property implementation based on some base classes provided by JavaFX:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final ReadOnlyBarProperty bar = new ReadOnlyBarProperty();

    public final Bar getBar() {
        return barProperty().get();
    }

    private void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar.set(bar);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Bar> barProperty() {
        return bar;
    }

    [...]

    private class ReadOnlyBarProperty extends ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase<Bar> {

        private Bar bar = null;

        @Override
        public final Bar get() {
            return bar;
        }

        private void set(Bar newValue) {
            if (!Objects.equals(bar, newValue)) {
                bar = newValue;
                fireValueChangedEvent();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object getBean() {
            return MyClass.this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

Then there are some rare cases where you want to provide your own property implementation. E.g. I've written a [SimpleEventHandlerProperty](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/blob/release-0.13/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-core/src/main/java/org/drombler/commons/fx/event/SimpleEventHandlerProperty.java) in [Drombler Commons](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/).

I hope these samples cleared things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

*It depends*.

There is a fairly common pattern in the standard JavaFX libraries of creating local or anonymous classes that extend one of the "base" classes (`ReadOnlyXXXPropertyBase` or `XXXPropertyBase`). In my experience, this is done usually for one of two reasons:

1. It's a read-only property whose value is managed from outside the property.
2. Something must happen internally when the property is invalidated.

To see an example of the first case take a look at the [source code of `ListPropertyBase`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/11/rt/file/d789718c6504/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/beans/property/ListPropertyBase.java). This property class has two properties of its own, `empty` and `size`, inherited from `ListExpression`. These properties, as expected, reflect the empty and size states of the contained `ObservableList`. The way these properties are implemented are as local classes but their values are managed by the `ObservableList` itself. The `ListPropertyBase` class simply has them fire change events when appropriate.

For the second case, the local or anonymous class will override the protected `invalidated` method provided by most (all?) of the `XXXPropertyBase` classes. This method is called when the property is invalidated. It allows one to react without the overhead of a listener. You can see this in action by looking at the [source code of `ButtonBase`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/11/rt/file/d789718c6504/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.java). For example, the `onAction` property:

```
public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onActionProperty() { return onAction; }
public final void setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> value) { onActionProperty().set(value); }
public final EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnAction() { return onActionProperty().get(); }
private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> onAction = new ObjectPropertyBase<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>() {
    @Override protected void invalidated() {
        setEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, get());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return ButtonBase.this;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "onAction";
    }
};
```

When the property is invalidated, the `invalidated` method registers/unregisters the `EventHandler` from the `Node`.

With all that said, if you don't need to add customized behavior stick to using `ReadOnlyXXXWrapper` for read-only properties and `SimpleXXXProperty` for read-write properties.

---

#### `Simple`?

Why do the concrete implementations have `Simple` in their name? Why not just have `XXXProperty` be the concrete implementation?

I can't give a definitive answer, as I wasn't involved in development, but I can offer a guess: The JavaFX developers wanted to provide multiple "extension points" that offer various degrees of "already implemented". Need full customization? Extend `XXXProperty`. Need some customization? Extend `XXXPropertyBase`. And so on.

And the `SimpleXXXProperty` classes needed names that didn't conflict with the `XXXProperty` class names. `Simple` fits because that's what they are—simple implementations. They do nothing but what the interfaces require.

---

#### Worth Mentioning

On an API level, virtually every JavaFX class exposes properties as either `ReadOnlyXXXProperty` or `XXXProperty`. Never is it `Property<SomeObject>` or `SimpleXXXProperty`. Basically, when it comes to properties, consider using `ReadOnlyXXXProperty` and `XXXProperty` as "programming to the interface". Just like you'd expose `List` instead of `ArrayList`.

I'd also consider that quote:

> This class provides a full implementation of a `Property` wrapping a `String` value.

To be misleading. If you look at the source of `StringProperty` is is certainly *not* a "full implementation". Maybe it's trying to say its the API level class? Maybe it's trying to say it implements all the necessary interfaces? Honestly, I have no idea...